# I want to validate a sentence which consist of punctuation marks using php?

Tags: php

I want to publish a quote text but need to validate input

need to validate following things -

1. no slashes
2. no html tags
3. no unicode
4. only text, dot, inverted comma and comma.

```
$x = 'Life is what happens when you’re busy making other plans.';
if (ctype_alnum(trim($x)) == true){
echo 'true';
}
```

this don't work. it don't validate if it includes dot, comma and inverted comma

Comment: What exactly do you want to "validate" about it?

Comment: added more details

Comment: [`preg_match('/^[a-z.,' ]+$/i', $x)`](https://regex101.com/r/ePZS7J/1)…?

Answer (score 0):

You almost got it right, you just need to replace all the white-spaces too.
`trim` doesn't remove all white space, only before and after the string.

```php
$x = 'Life is what happens when you’re busy making other plans.';
if (ctype_alnum(trim(str_replace(' ','',preg_replace('/[.,’]/', '', $x))))){
echo 'true';
}else{
    echo"false";
}
```

I used `preg_replace` to remove the comma, dot and inverted commas from the string, before validating it. Just all the `[.,’]` you want replaced

Comment: Made a edit to my answer, since I forgot about the comma, dot and inverted comma in the first post. Please let me know if there is any problems with this